# How to create a simple WebApp using Spring Boot in IntelliJ and JavaScript (AJAX) in VS Code

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-boot, web-applications

I am trying to create my very first webapplication - nothing fancy just a project to get started.

I have created a Spring Boot application in Java, mostly following [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) official spring.io tutorial (I left out the CORS part for now). The project consists of the `Greeting` class and the `GreetingController` which is a RestController.

Greeting.java

```
package com.example.demo.model;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

GreetingController.java:

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.model.Greeting;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        System.out.println("=== get greeting ===");
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Upon receiving a GET-request with the parameter `/greeting`, a new Greeting-object will be created and returned in JSON. When running this code and opening my browser on localhost:8080/greeting, the JSON of the greeting-object is shown. So, the Spring Boot application is up and running.

What might be important is that my resources folder is empty. The app.properties file is empty too.

[image: project structure]

I have furthermore created an index.html file in VS code (just mentioning this as my Spring Boot application is running in IntelliJ). I have also created a JavaScript file, hello.js, which is called in the header of index.html. The JavaScript file is sending a GET-request to localhost:8080/greeting upon loading the index.html page:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World!</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
            <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

hello.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        url: "http://localhost:8080/greeting", 
        success: function(data) {
            $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
            $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
        }
    }); 
});
```

When opening my index.html page in my browser (VS Code plugin: Open in Default Browser), I was expecting to see the ID and the Content of my Greeting-Object. But I did not. Nothing happens.

It seems that my understanding of how this should work is fundamentally wrong, but I cannot figure out where I am off. Can somebody help me understand what is going on?

==================================

Some information from developer tools:

My console doesn't reveal anything useful (to me). It appears only that a browser extension could not be loaded:

[image: console]

The Network section only shows that the index.html has been loaded. But the GET-request to my localhost was not initiated:

[image: network1]

[image: network2]

Comment: what do you see in your browser console and network tool?

Comment: @glaxy: It appears that my GET-request is never executed. I wonder why though. The `$(document).ready()` method should be executed after index.html has been fully loaded.

Comment: allright, I kinda figured it out: The problem was that I just opened the index.html in my default browser. If I open it using VS Code Plugin "Open in Live Server", it works. I mean, I run into a CORS-exception, but at least the rest request was send. The CORS-Exception can be fixed using @CrossOrigin(origin = "*") in my RestController.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Spring [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-jquery/) you can try this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/greeting"
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.greeting-id').append(data.id);
       $('.greeting-content').append(data.content);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's what I tried out first. Since I am not very familiar with promises though, I switched to the other code. Neither works.